# Webpack / Webpacker not serving styles with RSpec tests. webpack-dev-server not configured?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, rspec, webpack-dev-server, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm new to webpack and clearly missing something here. This seemed to be working until we upgraded our app to `rails 6.1` and `webpacker 5.4`. `yarn --version webpack` outputs `1.22.10`

Everything appears to get served correctly in the development environment. In the test environment some assets appear to get served(like some images and some react templates) but no styles are served and the app is totally unstyled.

One thing I noticed is that if I leave `webpack-dev-server` off in development mode, I get the same issue as test gets. This makes me think that the test env is not configured properly to work with `webpack-dev-server` but so far I cannot figure out how to connect them

The app has assets in two locations: `app/assets` and `app/frontend`

One interesting thing that I noticed is that the `public/packs` directory looks very different from the `public/packs-test` directory` although I can't see any reason why that should be true.

`public/packs` has a single file in it : `manifest.json`
`public/packs-test` has a ton of chunk files in it

Here is the relevant config

webpacker.yml

```
---
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect
default: &default
  source_path: app/frontend
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  resolved_paths: ['app/assets', 'vendor/assets']

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .erb
    - .jsx
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg
    - .json

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: true
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: true
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/
      aggregateTimeout: 300
      poll: 500

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true
  public_output_path: packs-test

production: &production
  <<: *default
  compile: false
  cache_manifest: true

webstaging:
  <<: *production

webtest:
  <<: *production

webdev:
  <<: *production
```

config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const erbLoader = require('./loaders/erb')
const svgLoader = require('./loaders/svg')
const addCommonsChunkPlugins = require('./plugins/commons-chunk')
const injectIndividualStylesheets = require('./individual-stylesheets')

// Set shorter hashes
environment.config.set('output.filename', '[name]-[hash:6].js')
environment.config.set('output.chunkFilename', '[name]-[chunkhash:6].chunk.js')

// More readable classnames for css modules
const cssLoader = environment.loaders
  .get('moduleCss')
  .use.find(el => el.loader === 'css-loader')
cssLoader.options.localIdentName = '[local]_[hash:base64:5]'

// Manually add any ES6 targeted vendor dependencies
// converts /node_modules/ to /node_modules(?!\/my-es6-targeted-module)/
const babelLoader = environment.loaders.get('babel')
const newExcludePattern = new RegExp(`${babelLoader.exclude.source}(?!\/better-youtube-api)`)
babelLoader.exclude = newExcludePattern

// Add erb loader (for images.js.erb)
environment.loaders.append('erb', erbLoader)

// Load svg files differently from css and js files
environment.loaders.insert('svg', svgLoader, { after: 'file' })

// Exclude svg extension from file loader
const fileLoader = environment.loaders.get('file')
fileLoader.exclude = /\.(svg)$/i

// Add commons chunk plugin for extracting common shared modules
addCommonsChunkPlugins(environment)

// Add individual stylesheets to webpack entries
injectIndividualStylesheets(environment)

module.exports = environment
```

config/webpack/development.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

config/webpack/test.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost", port: 3000 }
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'

  config.force_ssl = true

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true
  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure public file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{1.hour.seconds.to_i}"
  }

  # Separate file storage in the test environment
  config.active_storage.service = :test

  # Use inline job processing to make things happen immediately
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  config.x.enable_gtm = false
end
```

I would be extremely grateful for any insite as I have been fighting this for a while

Answer (score 0):

I still don't really know what was going on here or if it was resolvable but upgrading my webpack (not webpacker) version along with many sub dependencies solved this for me.